# Table using too much disk space

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I run the "Top disk usage by table" report in Sql Server Management Studio, it shows one of my tables using about 1.8GB of disk space:

[image]

The table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RecipeItems](
    [wo_id] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [invent_id] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [invent_dim_id] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ratio] [float] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I'd *roughly* estimate that with each row takes less than 200 bytes, and with only 7K records, this shouldn't take up more than 1-2MB. But obviously, this is not the case. What might be the reason this table uses so much storage?

Comment: Have you performed any big deletes on this table (e.g. did it used to store a lot more than 7K rows)? Have there been a lot of updates? Have you tried rebuilding the table (should be extremely quick)?

Comment: I haven't tried rebuilding or shrinking the database.

Comment: Are there *any* indexes (including primary or unique key constraints) on this table?

Comment: Yes, I do large updates and deletes on this table. In fact, I periodically delete all and bulk insert.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Chances are that a lot of data has been updated or deleted. Since it is a heap updates can lead to forwarding records. I would try this first:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.RecipeItems REBUILD;
```

Next I would consider adding a clustered index.

Do not run a shrink database command to fix this table, PLEASE.

When you perform your "delete all and bulk insert" I would do it this way, running a rebuild in the middle:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.RecipeItems;
ALTER TABLE dbo.RecipeItems REBUILD;
BULK INSERT dbo.RecipeItems FROM ...
```

If you add a clustered index you may want to do this a little differently. And if you can't use TRUNCATE, keep using DELETE, obviously. TRUNCATE will cause less log churn if the table is eligible, and since you are wiping out the table and re-populating it, it's not something you seem to need to recover from. In fact you might just consider dropping the table and re-creating it each time.

Comment: We don't know enough about the data structures to know whether TRUNCATE would be appropriate, or even work.

Comment: Ok, so keep using DELETE if TRUNCATE is not an option. That is hardly the point of my answer.

Comment: Thank you. I have been using `DELETE RecipeItems` and then actually doing a bulk insert from .NET code using the `SqlBulkCopy` class (I haven't looked into how it performs the bulk update under the hood). I don't do any UPDATEs, so do you still recommend the REBUILD approach?

Comment: @Eren yes, the same would be true whether or not you are doing updates in between.